# Connected component analysis, how to handle split components?

Tags: c++, image-processing, pattern-matching, image-recognition

I am developing an image recognition application. 
To recognize and classify symbols in an image the plan is to use the k-Nearest-Neighbours algorithm against a set of classified symbols for each connected component (ie. "group of connected pixels").

But how do I handle symbols which are split? (if the symbols were characters an example would be "i")

Comment: This question seems quite on-topic. @Closer: Be sure you understand OCR algorithms before casting a vote

Comment: A sample image, even a simplified mockup, would be very useful. Do you mean symbols or alphabetic characters? Do you expect more than one symbol per image? Do these symbols appear in groups/sequences or spread out? Any color info?

Answer (score 0):

Some heuristic:

1. Compare not only connected components but also circumscribed rectangles with background pixels. These rectangles can be extended up (for cases "i", "ä" and so on).
2. Define a metric taking into account the background pixels. For example add distance if pixels are the different, and substract if the same. In this case when you compare your extracted letter which similar "i" with "i" and "l" you will get shorter distance at "i". This is because white pixel between "dot" and "stick" will increase distance with "l".
3. It happens that "rn" is recognized as "m". To avoid this a metric must be such than "r" is closer to "rn" than "m". For my text I had enough of the metric, as described in paragraph 2 (:

Comment: Thanks for answering!
Am I getting this right: 
1) when building the k-NN sample set, I add the composite symbols, ie. a complete "i" or "ä", not "a+.+."
2) when comparing a connected component to the sample set, I try first the original connected component, and then the original connected component together with other "close" connected components? the resolved symbol is the closest match of the two? in the case of "ä", "a+.+." and "ä" wouldn't both have good scores?